# java.util.Scanner not working

Tags: java

I am using Rational Software Architect as my IDE, I am not able to import java.util.Scanner, it seems that Scanner is not available in the java.util package, am i supposed to include some jar file to use it.

Comment: It was introduced with java 1.5. What's the version of your JDK ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[java.util.Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) was introduced in version 1.5 ("Java 5"), I'm not familiar with Rational Software Architect, but probably you need to set your project to use the correct Java-version (1.5 or newer).

Comment: It seems that the Rational-products are based on Eclipse, so I guess the way of checking and changing used JDK should be (pretty much) the same: Right click on your project in the Project Explorer, select Build Path -> Configure Build Path... and check that the JDK/JRE is correct version. If it's not, change as needed (Remove the wrong one, click Add library -> JRE System Library -> select or browse for the correct one).

Answer (score 0):

No java.util.scanner is part of j2se 5 and 6
Which IDE are you using?
try a simple test. start a new java project with one file and try using scanner and see what happens

Comment: It is working if i open a new java project, but for my dynamic web project it doesnt work.

Comment: dynamic web project you say?what's your backend, tomcat or something else? The jars not only have to be part of your IDE but also of the container (tomcat, jetty, etc..). also sometimes you need explicitly to point to these jars in a config file or so, depending on your configuration. please give more details about the environment

Comment: i am using websphere application server v6.1, the project is using struts 1.3.10

Comment: a quick jar search shows that its part of the standard rt.jar http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/java.util.Scanner.1. i.e. it HAS to be there. one more experiment, create a new dynamic web project with the exact same configuration (regarding struts) and see what happens

Comment: also make sure that struts is using java 1.5 or java 6. This is really important

Comment: With a Dynamic Web Project you are targetting a specific WebSphere version. That version may be using an old version of Java. Maybe your target server is not configured properly.